# Remove black edges from existing image using the GD library

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm downloading an image that already has black edges.  Note: this isn't a result of me resizing an image.  How can I use the GD library to detect and remove these black edges?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is the cropped image using the script
[image]

Comment: will the black edges always be the whole height of the image?

Comment: No, either X or Y depending on the image.

Comment: Will there ever be both?

Comment: No, it will be one or the other.  But, the script will have to detect if it's X or Y.  I won't manually tell it for each one.

Comment: Will the width of the border on the top/right always equal the width of the border on the bottom/left ± 1px?

Comment: Yes, the black edge will always be equal to it's counterpart whether it's top / bottom OR right / left.

Comment: It will always be equal.

Comment: I've added another example of an image.

Comment: It appears as if the top is in one pixel difference than the bottom...

Comment: I'm not positive, but it could be.  If you think it is than it probably is.  The images were already like this.  I wasn't the one that resized them.

Comment: Were you able to come up with a solution?

Comment: I was... however, it takes a pretty long time.

Comment: Why have you posted the cropped image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to come up with a time-consuming fix to this. Do the images being stored *need* to be stored with those black borders? It'd be much better if you could run every image with the black borders through the following script (using php to loop through every image in the directory) and let php override the old, black-bordered image with the new, borderless image.

The approach I took was to create 4 loops:

1. To look at black borders on the right (loop through x -> loop through y)
2. To look at black borders on the left (loop through x -> loop through y)
3. To look at black borders on the bottom (loop through y -> loop through x)
4. To look at black borders on the top (loop through y -> loop through x)

Now, each of these loops had another loop in them which would loop through the other coordinate (ie., x->y or y->x). If the inner loop found that one of the pixels lying on the outer loop's line wasn't black, it broke the whole look. If it didn't find that, it would increase one to the counter.

At the end, we simply create a new image with the new dimensions and copy from the new to the old one.

```
<?php
$image_path = "jcMHt.jpg";

$jpg = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
$black = array("red" => 0, "green" => 0, "blue" => 0, "alpha" => 0);

$removeLeft = 0;
for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($jpg); $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($jpg); $y++) {
        if(imagecolorsforindex($jpg, imagecolorat($jpg, $x, $y)) != $black){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $removeLeft += 1;
}

$removeRight = 0;
for($x = imagesx($jpg)-1; $x > 0; $x--) {
    for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($jpg); $y++) {
        if(imagecolorsforindex($jpg, imagecolorat($jpg, $x, $y)) != $black){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $removeRight += 1;
}

$removeTop = 0;
for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($jpg); $y++) {
    for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($jpg); $x++) {
        if(imagecolorsforindex($jpg, imagecolorat($jpg, $x, $y)) != $black){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $removeTop += 1;
}

$removeBottom = 0;
for($y = imagesy($jpg)-1; $y > 0; $y--) {
    for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($jpg); $x++) {
        if(imagecolorsforindex($jpg, imagecolorat($jpg, $x, $y)) != $black){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $removeBottom += 1;
}

$cropped = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($jpg) - ($removeLeft + $removeRight), imagesy($jpg) - ($removeTop + $removeBottom));
imagecopy($cropped, $jpg, 0, 0, $removeLeft, $removeTop, imagesx($cropped), imagesy($cropped));

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($cropped); //change to `imagejpeg($cropped, $image_path);` to save
imagedestroy($cropped);
imagedestroy($jpg);
```

Comment: Wow nice script!  I notice when the script is done loading it shows the newly cropped image, but doesn't replace the old one.  How can I replace the old image with the newly cropped image?  Also, you were right about it being off by a pixel.  The script appears to leave a very slight black border; it's very slight though.  Check out the update to my question.  I've uploaded an image I used the script on.  You'll notice the very slight borders on the left and right.  Also, the left side appears to have 1 more pixel than the right.  Thanks Nile!

Comment: No, I've addressed the ±1px issue by using 8 loops instead of 4. The border you're seeing __is not__ black which is why my script does not crop it out. Check the comment in the script for how to make it save.

Comment: That worked.  I'll use it loop through a lot of images and modify the script to detect and work for all file extensions.  The slight border left over must be a lighter shade of black or something as you suggested.  Dude, nice script!  Thanks!

Comment: One more thing.  If that is a lighter shade of black and consistently leaves 5 px on every image.  Is there a way to add 5 px to each side for the crop?

Comment: Yes, instead of leaving `$removeLeft`, `$removeRight`, `$removeTop`, and `$removeBottom` at 0, you can change them to something like 5. Find each of these variables before each corresponding loop. Another way is to just add 5 to each of these variables before assigning the `$cropped` function.

Comment: How would you approach some tolerance to $black, let's say from 000 to 333 ? Web images like youtube thumbs have no real solid color border in most cases through pre compressing/scaling.

Comment: @fiveDust I'm not sure what you mean by "tolerance... from 000 to 333"

Comment: Nile, what I meant was to cut the framing color based on  a color range or shade range, lets say between 0x000000 0x333333

Comment: @fiveDust Right.. okay. I guess what you could do would be to specific a specific range (i.e., because GD uses rgb, not hex, you would set a tolerance level to 51 because 0x33 = 51), then make a for loop padding the array `$black` 51 in both directions (unless negative, which applies in this case), and compare each of those arrays to the color index